# Why Angular 5 FileReader not reading entire image?

Tags: typescript, angular5, angular2-forms

I am using angular 5 in my project. When I upload a file using FileReader; Its not reading properly. Its corresponding base64 string is breaking from middle. When I compare this with online base64 converter both encrypted strings are mismatch. My typescript code is given below.

```
<input type="file" (change)="changeListener($event)">

changeListener($event): void {
  this.readThis($event.target);
}
readThis(inputValue: any): void {
  var file: File = inputValue.files[0];
  var myReader: FileReader = new FileReader();
  myReader.readAsDataURL(file);
  myReader.onloadend = (e) => {
  this.Registration.Image = myReader.result.split(',')[1];
 }    
}
```

How to solve this issue?